# Did the word "fairies" originate after the creation of stories about fairies?

Tags: folklore, fairies, names

From [Wiktionary: Fairy : Etymology](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fairy#Etymology)

> From Middle English fairie, from Old French faerie, the -erie abstract of fae, from Vulgar Latin Fāta (“goddess of fate”), from Latin fātum (“fate”)

This seems to indicate that 'fairies' is a term that was made up to encompass all those Fairy Tales (like how all/most Pagan Gods -> Demons in Christianity in the past). That would indicate that what we call 'fairies' were, in the languages that their stories originated from, ['sidhe'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sidhe), ['alfar' (Elves)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alfr#Old_Norse), or [pigsie (Pixies)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pixie)...

Could someone confirm my theory?

Comment: Are you asking for when tales of fairies first appeared?

Comment: @HDE226868 - No... I think I'm asking if 'fairies' is a term that was made up to encompass all those Fairy Tales, sorta like how all/most Pagan Gods -> Demons in Christianity in the past. ... Perhaps Ling.SE would be a better fit?

Comment: We have some questions on [tag:names] and related topics; I think this is fine here. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Old English word for fairies is [*elf*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=elf) (Online Etymology Dictionary):

> “one of a race of powerful supernatural beings in Germanic folklore,” Old English *elf* (Mercian, Kentish), *ælf* (Northumbrian), *ylfe* (plural, West Saxon) “sprite, fairy, goblin, incubus,” from Proto-Germanic **albiz* (cognates: Old Saxon *alf,* Old Norse *alfr,* German *alp* “evil spirit, goblin, incubus”), origin unknown; according to Watkins, possibly from PIE **albho-* “white.”

The Old French word for fairies is [*faerie*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=fairy):

> “land of fairies, meeting of fairies; enchantment, magic, witchcraft, sorcery” (12c.), from *fae* “fay,” from Latin *fata* “the Fates,” plural of *fatum* “that which is ordained; destiny, fate,” from PIE **bha-* “to speak” (see *fame* (n.)).

The entry for [*fate*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=fate) notes that it’s also connected to the concept of guiding spirits in general and not just specifically the Fates, just as an *elf* is rooted in the concept of mischievous spirits in general.

Thus, *faerie* is simply the French word for the concept, just as *elf* is the Germanic word and *sidhe* is the Gaelic word for it. The development of the English language is such that a lot of native words were replaced or augmented with their French equivalents. For example, the native English word for the concept of fate is *wyrd,* which still survives as one of the meanings of *weird,* but is mostly supplanted by the Latinate word *fate,* very much like how *elf* shares with the Latinate *fairy.*

Comment: Are you saying that an elf, a fairy, and a sidhe are essentially the same type of being/species ?

Comment: You can't assume in such a way that words used in different languages and cultures express the same concept. There are ontological issues here.

Comment: @TheEarth I’m talking about English language and culture, which has roots in Germanic and French languages. Modern English typically uses the two roots interchangeably, except that the French-rooted words typically have a higher register than the Germanic-rooted words, which we mostly perceive as more vulgar or folksy. For another example, French _beef_ is a high-register word for meat whereas Germanic _cow_ is a low-register word for a farm animal. In some cases, like _weird,_ the Germanic roots have become archaic or obsolete.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you mean by that comment though, so if you had some other criticism in mind, please elaborate.

Comment: I was responding to your statement that "*faerie* is simply the French word for the concept, just as *elf* is the Germanic word and *sidhe* is the Gaelic word for it" although that can't have been what you had in mind when you said you were talking about English language and culture. Usage of each of those words developed within a culture and came with meanings that in some respects at least were specific to it. Moreover I think that accounts for some of the difference between the meanings of *fairy* (or *faerie*) and *elf* in English.

Comment: True, the words do have some different connotations!

Comment: That said, the meat of this question is, roughly, did we make up the word “fairy” to encapsulate all of the various other words for fairies, and the answer to that is still _no_! We just settled on the French-derived word as a preferred term, the way we settled on a lot of other French-derived words for things.

Answer (score 17):

Since this is more a philological question, I'm going with this somewhat different take on the matter from noted philologist J.R.R. Tolkien:

> *Fairy,* as a noun more or less equivalent to *elf,* is a relatively modern word, hardly used until the Tudor period. The first quotation in the Oxford Dictionary (the only one before A.D. 1450) is significant. It is taken from the poet Gower: *as he were a faerie.* But this Gower did not say. He wrote *as he were of faerie,* "as if he were come from faerie".

The source for this is his noted essay ["On Fairy Stories"](http://excellence-in-literature.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/fairystoriesbytolkien.pdf), pp 3 (PDF). (I have taken one liberty in transcribing it: the PDF to which I linked appears to have dropped the italics. Tolkien used italics heavily; my memory of first reading "On Fairy Stories" includes that customary italicization; so I have attempted to recreate it as best I can. If I got it wrong, that's on me.)

Anyway, it's bracing to hear a professional imply that the use of the term "fairies" stems mainly from a publisher's error. Tolkien certainly knew his field, and was probably familiar with the occasional accident in transcription carrying large linguistic consequences.

For what it's worth, Tolkien did not hesitate to place Feerie - the land, not the inhabitants - in its proper place in mythology & folklore. From the same essay, on page 4:

> Faerie contains many things besides elves and fays, and besides dwarfs, witches, trolls, giants, or dragons: it holds the seas, the sun, the moon, the sky; and the earth, and all things that are in it: tree and bird, water
>   and stone, wine and bread, and ourselves, mortal men, when we are enchanted.

That rather magnificent bit of wordsmithing outlines the beginning's of Tolkien's theme for the essay. I won't issue spoilers, but this admittedly fairly long piece might be of considerable interest to mythology.SE.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'Fairy' is most commonly used to describe a mystical entity that holds no true connection with our physical world. Because of this non-connection, the word "Fairy" has a neutral connotation and is used to describe the powerful forces of nature and the mystical entities that inhabit nature.  It is likely that because old Pagan religions are deeply entangled with the forces of nature, the term "Fairy Tales" came naturally to describe stories of mystical encounters in the forests during that time.  The modern interpretation of a "Fairy" has evolved to something that is still evolved with the forest but is far from what the original historical context suggested. Think... mysterious weather and swirling clouds (old pagan view of "fairies") vs.. Tinker Bell (modern interpretation of "fairies")

Comment: May I encourage you to [cite reputable sources](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/q/105/62) (e.g. not wikipedia)? Doing so makes it easy to know if your answer is right, and also provides starting points to users who would like to learn more about the topic.

Comment: i recently killed my computer with all my mythology books... i will add some references when i can take the time to dig through my collection and find the correct title. until then, i don't want to guess at which book i got the information from. Thank you Christofian :)

Comment: Well, this answer is about how the 'meaning' of fairy evolved over time, not how the word 'fairy' even appeared... But, if this answer is correct, then a likely path to the current usage of "Fairy", would be that "Fae" was first used to mean: "Natural Forces that control our Fate", which connects 'Natural Forces" and "Fate" (Fate 'cause the Latin parts of the etymology I posted in the OP), and then evolved from there to current "Fairy"... But, that's just speculation...